# CompletableFuture.acceptEither

Tags: java, multithreading

I am experimenting with `CompletableFuture` API from JDK8, trying out `acceptEither()` method from it. Please have a look at the code below (and then I would put forth my concern):

```
public class AcceptEither {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompletableFuture<Double> completableFuture2 
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(TaskSupplier::getSomeArbitraryDouble);

        CompletableFuture<Double> completableFuture3 
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(TaskSupplier::getAnotherArbitraryDouble);

        CompletableFuture<Void>completableFutureForAcptEither 
            = completableFuture2.acceptEither(completableFuture3, (val)-> {
                      System.out.println("val: "+val);
                });


        /*while(true){
            if(completableFutureForAcptEither.isDone())
                break;
            System.out.println("task did not complete");
        }
        System.out.println("task finally completed");*/

        System.out.println("exiting main method");


    }

}


class TaskSupplier{
    static double getSomeArbitraryDouble(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 5;
    }
    static double getAnotherArbitraryDouble(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Please note the commented infinite while loop! In this situation the output is as follows:

```
exiting main method
```

We can see that `CompletableFuture` returned by `acceptEither()` could not execute the supplied `action`.

However, if I un-comment the infinite while loop, I get the following output:

```
task did not complete
task did not complete
task did not complete
val: 10.0
task did not complete
task did not complete
task did not complete
task did not complete
task finally completed
exiting main method
```

Following is the documentation of the acceptEither method:

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> acceptEither(CompletionStage<? extends T> other,
                                            Consumer<? super T> action)

Description copied from interface: CompletionStage
Returns a new CompletionStage that, when either this or the other given stage complete normally, is executed with the corresponding result as argument to the supplied action. See the CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.
```

Quite noticeably this time the `CompletableFuture` returned by `acceptEither()` executed.

Following these observations I can see some dependency between the main-thread (running the main method) and the thread (from the Fork Join Common Pool) which would execute the `action`.

I feel that the main thread should not reach its end of life, before pooled thread executes the supplied `action`! But I am not sure of this deduction at all. Please enlighten me what's happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thread doesn't wait for tasks in Fork Join Common Pool. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) of common pool says:

> However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program System.exit(int). Any program that relies on asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination should invoke commonPool().awaitQuiescence, before exit.

You can also use your own executor by using the other methods of CompletableFuture which accept an executor in signature. Doing that, all submitted tasks will be executed on your executor.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {...}, executor);
...
```

And then shutdown the executor at the end of the main thread

```
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: I tried the following:
`Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`
and even provided a custom Executor implementation as follows: 
Executor exec = new Executor() {
   
   @Override
   public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
    new Thread(runnable, "My-Super-Man").start();
   }
  };
But these do not work as expected. I still have the same problem. Any suggestions.

Comment: @nawazish-stackoverflow These 3 lines work as expected for me. It prints "exiting main method + 
val: 10.0" before exiting really. Make sure to change the both call to `supplyAsync()` of `CompletableFuture` to pass it the executor. Otherwise, you have still the same problem as before.

Comment: Yes it worked; thanks a lot for teaching me something new! Thanks again.